# Groups policy not applying on my VPN users

Tags: vpn

Hi is any one can help me in below scenario..

I have configured VPN server on my AWS server and created multiple VPN user. After that i have created some groups policy like map network drive, hide their locka drive. But user are connected not through VPN but these policies are not working. I have run gpupdae / force as well.

Please help me on this.

Comment: *gpupdate /force

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what setup you are using?

You have setup a VPN server, yes but what kind of VPN server: OpenVPN, Microsoft VPN server or another kind server? The solution to your question will be completely different depending on the setup.

Also: Is the client computer a member of the domain you want to connect to via VPN?

Any computers that are domain members will look for group policy settings at `\\DC\sysvol\DOMAIN\Policies`, where:

`DC = FQDN of Domain Controller` like `host.ad.domain.com`.

`DOMAIN = FQDN of the domain` like `ad.domain.com`.

---

If the clients is connected via OpenVPN things looks a bit more tricky.

It is possible to map network drives and hide local drives using a PowerShell script when the client is connected to VPN server by using the `up` directive in the client configuration file.

And you can do the opposite when by using the `down` directive.

However I would be **very carefull** when hiding local drives, as you may end up messing to much with the client computer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is a Windows AD since you executed the gpupdate / force

I had the same issue and what I did is to assure that my remote PC could connect to the AD server(s), which were also and DNS servers. I added to their IP in the the Network settings as static and executed the gpupdate /force at least 3-4 times.

Then restarted the PC and the policies were there